# modify char array passed to C dll c#

Tags: c#, c, string, dll, marshalling

I am simply trying to pass a buffer to a C dll from C#, have the C func fill the buffer in, and then do something with the buffer  back in the C# code.  But I'm getting garbage back in the buffer. Here's the C:

```
    extern "C" __declspec( dllexport )      
    int  cFunction(char *plotInfo, int bufferSize) 
    {
        strcpy(plotInfo, "text");
        return(0);
    }
```

c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
{
 [DllImport("mcDll.dll",
     CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet=CharSet.Unicode)]

    public static extern int cFunction( StringBuilder theString, int bufferSize);
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder(55);
        int result = cFunction( s, 55);
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Native function operates with ANSI chars. Just remove `CharSet.Unicode` from your import definition.